# Counting mark via strings

Tags: c++, string

Here l changed my code and my main problem is how to find mark when 3 numbers are typed...

l should input school subject and 3 marks and it should calculate my final mark (for example math 3 3 4 program should write final mark in math is 3 (when calculated it 3.33 so  mark is 3)). it is placed  in string s1[30]. My idea was to  detach string to parts based on empty space  but when l test program it  prints  NULL  instead of subject...any idea where is mistake ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void kopiranje(char *s,char *s2,char *s3)
 { 

    int i;
    char  *ocena;
    for( i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {   
        *(s2+i)=*(s+i); 
        if (*(s2+i)== ' ' )  *(s2+i)='\0';  
    }

} 


int main ()
{
  char s[30],s2[30],s3[30];
  char *ocena;
  printf("\nUnesi predmet i ocene:\n");
  printf("======================================\n");
  gets(s);
  kopiranje(s,s2,s3);

  printf("======================================");
  printf("\nZakljucna ocena iz predmeta %s je %s",s2);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use function `strtok`to split a string in tokens. And instead of `gets` it is much better to use `fgets`

As for the loop

```
for(int i=0;i<strlen(s1);i++)
{
    if((s1[i]==' ')&&(s1[i]=!"\0")) predmet=s1[i];      
}
```

then it shall not be compiled because there is a typo, Must be **!=** instead of **=!** and it has no any sense. You store ' ' in predmet.

By the way function main in C shall be defined as `int main( void )` if it has no parameters.

Comment: LoL I just realised what l typed :D lm epic fool thx for the help :D